# ArrayList<String> from String property on ArrayList<Thing>

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Thing` with an `ArrayList<Tag> tags` property:

```
class Thing {
    private ArrayList<Tag> tags;
    ...
}

class Tag {
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

And I need to make a `List` of the `description` strings of the tags

I have this, and it seems extremely cumbersome:

```
tags = thing.tags
            .stream()
            .map(tag -> tag.getDescription())
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Is there some simple way I've totally overlooked to "`map()`" a list?

Note that the type in and out doesn't have to be `ArrayList` in my application if some other "list" type thing would make it easier.
'

Comment: Context: I'm new to java, coming from python/js kind of background, where you can map arrays with ease.

Comment: `toList()` should be enough here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--

Comment: `tags = thing.tags.stream().map(tag->tag.getDescription()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: You can also replace `.map(tag -> tag.getDescription())` with a [Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html): `.map(Tag::getDescription)`.

Comment: As always, input on how to improve this question would be appreciated with the downvote.

Comment: I edited the question a bit for you: 1) don't assume that readers know the structure of your code (what do you mean by "I have a `Thing`?" -- make it clearer by saying "I have a class named `Thing`", etc.). 2) Format your code. 3) Same for `Tag`. show the structure of `Tag` relevant to this question. As for the down-votes, it is an unfortunate habit of some SO users.

Comment: Also I suggest using `List<String> tags` instead of `ArrayList<String> tags` (prefer interfaces over concrete classes).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't resent the downvotes, it's OK to get critical feedback.  I appreciate the trouble you took to help improve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List does not have a map method as Stream does. What you have is the way to do this.

You can make it slightly more succinct by using `Collectors.toList()` instead

Comment: Thanks - that's a nice start.  Is there a choice of data type for the 'collection' of `tags` on the `Thing` that does have a `map()`?   Or an alternative way to think about getting "the bunch of strings" from the tags on the `Thing` that doesn't involve calling for a `stream` then re-collecting after?

Comment: No, `map` was introduced in Java 1.8 on the `Stream` class as part of the Streams API. All of the standard collections will require you to first call `stream()`. While it's a little tedious, note that calling `stream()` does not copy the whole source collection to a new `Stream` object (which would consume O(n) memory); rather, the `Stream` is an adapter for the source collection.